# Change the text color of the popup menu

Tags: android

I am using Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar theme. I am getting a white background for popup menu and also the color of menu item is white that makes it invisible. I tried many solutions with no success.

This is my styles.xml

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">#000000</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu</item>
    <item name="android:textAppearanceLargePopupMenu">@style/myPopupMenuTextAppearanceLarge</item>
    <item name="android:textAppearanceSmallPopupMenu">@style/myPopupMenuTextAppearanceSmall</item>
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>

<style name="PopupMenu" parent="@android:style/Widget.PopupMenu">
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#000000</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">12sp</item>
</style>

<style name="myPopupMenuTextAppearanceSmall" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.DeviceDefault.Widget.PopupMenu.Small" tools:ignore="NewApi">
    <item name="android:textColor">#000000</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">15sp</item>
</style>

<style name="myPopupMenuTextAppearanceLarge" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.DeviceDefault.Widget.PopupMenu.Large" tools:ignore="NewApi">
    <item name="android:textColor">#000000</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">25sp</item>
</style>
```

This is the toolbar

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/toolbar"
    android:elevation="8dp"
    app:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    app:title="Troll Cricket" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add these lines to your Toolbar.xml file.

```
app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
```

This will allow you to have a dark toolbar and light-themed overflow menu.